# Interactive form not rendering correctly building a pdf document on Linux Mint using MikTex

Tags: miktex, linux, forms, rendering

I'm trying to build a simple PDF document with an interactive formular using the eform package, following this documentation:
http://mirror.las.iastate.edu/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/acrotex/doc/eformman.pdf

My main focus is on the checkboxes, because I need them for my application.

Based on the documentation I build this small example `acroforms.tex`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[dvips]{eforms}

\everyCheckBox{\BC{.690 .769 .871}\BG{.941 1 .941}\textColor{1 0 0}}

\begin{document}
    % Content containing form fields, such as...
    Don't \pushButton[\CA{Push Me}]{myButton}{}{12bp},
    I fall down easily.

    This is my checkbox:
    \checkBox[\symbolchoice{circle}]{myCheck}{10bp}{10bp}{On}
\end{document}
```

And build it with this makefile on Linux Mint 19.3 using MikTex 2.9.7050:

```
all: acroforms.pdf

acroforms.pdf: acroforms.ps
    ps2pdf -dEmbedAllFonts=true acroforms.ps

acroforms.ps: acroforms.dvi
    dvips acroforms.dvi

acroforms.dvi: acroforms.tex
    pdflatex -output-format=dvi acroforms.tex
    pdflatex -output-format=dvi acroforms.tex
```

The PDF viewer Evince is able to render it correctly. However, the build in reader in Vivaldi (Chromium), and the java library PDFBox, developed by Apache, are not able to render the form.

Screenshots:
[image]

Nevertheless, all three applications (Evince, Chromium & Apache PDFBox) are able to render the original pdf of the documentation correctly. Since they are all able to render the documentation, I assume the problem on my side.

Screenshots:
[image]

I also tried to use the hyperref package directly with the exact same result. What am I missing?

Comment: I don;t think any of the webbased PDF viewers supports these features. We tested them out at one point to use a form based PDF for an exam. And had to conclude that on linux Evince would work, not much else. Adobe reader would work on windows, not much else.

Comment: I'm rather sure that the author of eforms uses distiller to produce the documentation, so there could be differences to the ps2pdf output. If you have access to distiller you could try it instead. The ghostscript of miktex is a bit old (9.25), you could try a newer one.

Comment: Sorry for the delay!

@ulrike-fischer That's a good point! Unfortunately I have no access to distiller. Further, distiller wouldn't be a good option in my case since Adobe dropped the server version of distiller and my document needs to be generated automatically.

I've now tried to generate the PDF with ghostscript 9.52 and MiKTeX 2.9.7350 in a docker container based on Ubuntu 18.04. Additionally, I tried ps2pdf with different different compatibility levels up to PDF version 1.7 but with the same result as before.